# TypeError: get_cell_value() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, pygame

im new to pygame and im making a tictactoe game following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08VAdznyuSo&list=PL1P11yPQAo7pJT26yr1_cmfS1g_RX7b4d&index=5

this is some of my code:
tictactoe.py

```
player = "X"


class Grid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid_lines = [((0, 200), (600, 200)),  # first horizontal line
                           ((0, 400), (600, 400)),  # second horizontal line
                           ((200, 0), (200, 600)),  # first vertical line
                           ((400, 0), (400, 600))]  # second vertical line
        self.grid = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]

    def draw(self, win):
        for line in self.grid_lines:
            pygame.draw.line(win, BLACK, line[0], line[1], 2)

    def get_cell_value(self, x, y):
        return self.grid[y][x]

    def set_cell_value(self, x, y, value):
        self.grid[y][x] = value

    def get_mouse(self, x, y, player):
        if player == "X":
            self.get_cell_value(x, y, "X")
        elif player == "O":
            self.get_cell_value(x, y, "O")

    def print_grid(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            print(row)


# game loop
running = True
grid = Grid()


while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                grid.get_mouse(pos[0]//200, pos[1]//200, player)
                if player == "X":
                    player == "O"
                else:
                    player == "X"

                grid.print_grid()

    win.fill(WHITE)
    grid.draw(win)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

and when I try to run it. this error showed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NJ/PycharmProjects/pylab/tictactoe.py", line 58, in <module>
    grid.get_mouse(pos[0]//200, pos[1]//200, player)
  File "C:/Users/NJ/PycharmProjects/pylab/tictactoe.py", line 37, in get_mouse
    self.get_cell_value(x, y, "X")
TypeError: get_cell_value() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I dont know whats wrong, the code is almost the exact replica of the one in the tutorial. Been staring at the code for hours, 'trial and error' but cant get it running. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've confused `set_cell_value` and `get_cell_value`. In `get_mouse` you have to call `set_cell_value` rather than `get_cell_value`:

```py
class Grid:
    # [...]

    def get_mouse(self, x, y, player):
        if player == "X":
            self.set_cell_value(x, y, "X")
        elif player == "O":
            self.set_cell_value(x, y, "O")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an additional positional parameter into here:

`self.get_cell_value(x, y, "X")`

However had only provided space for two positional parameters in:

`get_cell_value(self, x, y)`

Comment: I think it should be `self.set_cell_value()`